Solving a leader follower (Stackelberg) game
I am trying to solve the following multi leader single follower game with two sellers and one buyer using a best response approach.
Seller 1's objective: $$\max_{p_{1}} \quad p_{1}d_{1} \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad 0 \leq p_{1} \leq 5$$
Seller 2's objective: $$\max_{p_{2}} \quad p_{2}d_{2} \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad 0 \leq p_{2} \leq 5$$
Buyer's objective: $$\min_{d_{1},d_{2}} \quad p_{1}d_{1}+p_{2}d_{2} \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad d_{1}+d_{2} \geq 8 \\
\quad \quad \quad0 \leq d_{1}, d_{2} \leq 5$$
Here, $p$'s are prices set by the sellers and $d$'s are the units of item the buyer buys from each seller.
My solution to the buyer's best response is$$
R(p_{1},p_{2})=\begin{cases}
    (5,3) & when \quad p_{1}<p_{2},\\
    (3,5) & when \quad p_{1}>p_{2},\\
    (d_{1},8-d_{1}) & when \quad p_{1}=p_{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Basically, buyer's response have multiple (infinite) solutions if $p_{1}=p_{2}$. Let's assume that $d_{1} = d_{2}$ or $R = (4,4)$ when $p_{1} = p_{2}$. Does this problem has a Nash equilibrium?

If seller 1 reduces its price to $p_1=4.9$, why would seller 2 then not reduce its price to $p_2=4.8$?  I doubt $p_1=5,p_2=5$ is a Nash equilibrium.

Sorry! I should have clarified that I was using an iterative method with step size 0.1 to solve the problem. So, if we start from $(5,5)$ and seller 1 reduces it's price to $4.9$ in the first turn, seller 2 can reduce it's own price at best to $4.9$. Maybe it is not the best way to solve it then?

@Henry If we go your way, the sellers will reduce their price in each turn until one (suppose, seller 1) reaches to the price of $3.0$ and the other one is at $3.1$. Now, seller 2 will not go down to $2.9$ (profit $14.5$), rather it makes more sense for it to set the price at $5$ (profit $15$). It is obvious that now it will follow the same pattern again with seller 1 setting its price to $4.9$. Does that mean this problem has no Nash equilibrium?

Let's review all the cases to determine if there is an NE.
If $p_1 < p_2$, then we are not at an NE because $p_1$ would prefer to increase their price, i.e., $p_1' = \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}$ would still be lower than $p_2$, so the demand would be the same, but seller 1 would be getting more profit.
If $p_2 < p_1$, we are in the same situation as above but with Seller 1 and Seller 2's roles reversed. Therefore, we only need to investigate what happens when $p_1 = p_2$.
When $p_1=p_2$, the Buyer is equally satisfied with $(d_1,d_2)=(x,8-x)$ for $x\in[3,5]$.
For Seller 1, they are making $p_1 x$ but could decrease their price to be making $(p_1-\epsilon)5$. As long as $\epsilon$ satisfies $(p_1-\epsilon)5 > p_1 x \implies \epsilon < \frac{(5-x)}{5}p_1$, they will prefer to decrease their price to have more demand, which results in an overall increase in profit. Notice that Seller 1 will not decrease their price if $\frac{(5-x)}{5}p_1 = 0 \implies p_1=0 \text{ or } x=5$. Similarly, Seller 1 would prefer increasing their price making $(p_1+\epsilon)3$, as long as $(p_1+\epsilon)3 > p_1 x \implies \epsilon > \frac{(x-3)}{3}p_1$ and $p_1+\epsilon \leq 5$ (i.e., their current profit $p_1x < 15$).
For Seller 2, they are making $p_2 (8-x)$ but could decrease their price to be making $(p_2-\delta)5$. As long as $\delta$ satisfies $(p_2-\delta)5 > p_2 (8-x) \implies \delta < \frac{(x-3)}{5}p_2$, they will prefer to decrease their price to have more demand, which results in an overall increase in profit. Notice that Seller 2 will not decrease their price if $\frac{(x-3)}{5}p_2 = 0 \implies p_2=0 \text{ or } x=3$. Similarly, Seller 2 would prefer increasing their price making $(p_2+\delta)3$, as long as $(p_2+\delta)3 > p_2 (8-x) \implies \delta > \frac{(5-x)}{3}p_2$ and $p_2+\delta \leq 5$ (i.e., their current profit $p_2(8-x) < 15$).
Combining all of this, we will be at an NE if neither Seller wants to increase or decrease their price. For Seller 1, they will not decrease if $p_1 = 0$ or $x=5$ and not increase if $p_1x \geq 15$. The only case where Seller 1 is satisfied is when $x = 5$ and $p_1=p_2\geq 3$. For Seller 2, they will only be satisfied if $x=3$ and $p_1=p_2\geq 3$. Since we can't have $x$ equal to 3 and 5, one of the Sellers will not be satisfied and change their strategy. Therefore, there is no NE.
